# Three.js Perspective Camera X axis is flipped

Tags: three.js

I have a scene with two camera, one is Orthographic and the other is a perspective, 
when orthographic camera is active everything looks normal, but perspective camera shows the scene X axis upside down, is there any way to fix it? 
my two cameras are added to the scene normally:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50,4 / 3,0.1,10000);
cameraO = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-2, 2, -2, 2, 1, 100);
```

here is an example : https://jsfiddle.net/g7juxm2q/12/
switch cameras by pressing "P" and "O".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not that the perspective camera has its axis flipped. The problem is that you're declaring your orthographic camera with a negative `top` and positive `bottom` parameters. Top is typically +y and bottom should be -y, as outlined in the [OrthoCam docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/cameras/OrthographicCamera)

```js
// Docs:
OrthographicCamera( left, right, top, bottom, near, far );

// Your implementation has top as -2, bottom as +2
THREE.OrthographicCamera(-2, 2, -2, 2, 1, 100);
```

Comment: Thank you,my bad, I fixed that, but the issue now is why red axis is pointing toward negative?

Comment: That's because you're setting your cameras to look from the top-down when you do `cameraO.position.set(0,10, 0)`. If you want it to look straight-ahead, you should do `cameraO.position.set(0, 0, 10)`, since the position follows `(x, y, z)` order. I recommend you spend some time playing with the Threejs editor to get acquainted with the axes: https://threejs.org/editor/ x: right-left, y: top-down, z: backward-forward

Comment: Thank you, I edited my comment to make more scenes, the original issue is that still can't get the Red and Blue axis to show toward positive X, and positive Z. I appreciate if you could help me with that.

Comment: Ah, that's due to a problem when the camera is pointing *exactly* down at a 90-degree angle. It's called gimbal-lock, and it occurs when the camera doesn't know which way is "up" anymore, so you'll get weird results. It happens in real-life too, when you look exactly down, there is no way to figure out which way is "up" anymore. To fix this issue, you can give the camera a very slight offset, so it's at 89.99 degrees, and that way it'll know which way "up" is: https://jsfiddle.net/marquizzo/274qaf0g/3/

Comment: I see, while X is correct, can we also point the Z toward positive now somehow?

Comment: That is correct. +x is towards the right, and +z is towards the user, so when looking down, it'll appear to be pointing towards the bottom of the screen. See here: https://threejs.org/editor/ to understand how z (the blue arrow) would look when you're looking straight-down.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you !!